# Grundy function for first to 100 game

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-game-theory

Two players alternately pick integers from 1 to 10 until the sum reaches at least 100. The same number can be used more than once. The first person to reach at least 100 wins.

What is the Grundy number?

Start with the losing position with G-number 0 and then decide the other positions G-number.

Comment: Have you found the rule for P positions?

Comment: Is that 89 ,78 ,67, 56, 45, 34, 23, 12, and 1 ?

Comment: That is correct.   Those are zero because the next to move loses.

Comment: Ok, so what is my next step?

Comment: it's periodic with period 11, and the winning strategy is to be first and choose 1. But how do I formulate mex and Grundy for this?

Answer (score 0):

You have a nim heap going up to the next $11k+1$.  For example, playing anything else than $1$ from $88$ is losing, so the only value you can move to from $88$ is to $0$, so $88$ is $*1$.  Then $87$ can move to $0, *1$, so it has value $*2$ and so on.

Comment: 86 can move 0,*1,*2
85 can move 0,*1,*2,*3
84 can move 0,*1,*2,*3,*4
83 can move 0,*1,*2,*3,*4,*5
82 can move 0,*1,*2,*3,*4,*5,*6
81 can move 0,*1,*2,*3,*4,*5,*6,*7
80 can move 0,*1,*2,*3,*4,*5,*6,*7,*8
79 can move 0,*1,*2,*3,*4,*5,*6,*7,*8,*9
78 can move 0,*1,*2,*3,*4,*5,*6,*7,*8,*9,*10
77 can move 0


Does that mean that the grundy function is 11?

Comment: It seems that $G(11a +b) = \ast(b-1)$ for $b \in \{0,\ldots,10\}$

Comment: I am only aware of a grundy function on a position of a game, not on the whole game.  My example above shows $G(87=*2)$.  There is no position $n$ with $G(n)=11$